# How to know feature table's clear selection event in older version of ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, dojo

I am using ArcGIS's feature table for showing data. I know that in new version clear-selection event fires when I click Clear Selection menu item from options.

Is there any other way to know about Clear Selection for lower version of ArcGIS? I want to know that Clear Selection is clicked from options.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understood your question, I will explain about ArcGIS 9.3 because you tagged ArcGIS 10.0. Thus, I am not sure are you talking about version 10 or need older than 10 like 9.3.

You can clear selection from Options as you already knew or from `Selection Menu -> Clear selection`

Using [ArcGIS 9.3](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Selecting_features_interactively) and under the section `Selecting features by clicking them in the map` it is written in the Tip section the following:

> - To deselect all selected features at once, click the map where there    are no features, click a feature of a layer that is not
>     selectable,    or click the Clear Selected Features tool on the Tools
>     toolbar.

To [clear selection  from the table](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Selecting_records_in_a_table):

> 1. Click Options in the table window and click Select All.
> 2. You can also click the box in top-left corner of the table view next to field heading to select all or deselect all records.
>
> **Tips**
>
> - The Selection menu contains additional tools for selecting features.
> - You can right-click the row button on the left side of the table and    be able to deselect individual records.